Issue with my makefile, how can I get it to compile?
When using this makefile
compile: scanner.o listing.o
    g++ -o compile scanner.o listing.o
    
scanner.o: scanner.c listing.h tokens.h
    g++ -c scanner.c

scanner.c: scanner.l
    flex scanner.l
    mv lex.yy.c scanner.c

listing.o: listing.cc listing.h
    g++ -c listing.cc

I get these errors, what could be the issue?
jeannetteadorante@LAPTOP-CIB2C03C:~$ make
g++ -o compile scanner.o listing.o
    /usr/bin/ld:listing.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
    /usr/bin/ld:listing.o:5: syntax error
    `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: compile] Error 1
jeannetteadorante@LAPTOP-CIB2C03C:~$

Using Ubuntu, I tried running the makefile and received the following error

TLDR: delete the intermediate files and run make again rm *.o; make
The thing about make is that it bases its decisions on what to use as-is and what to recompile on the timestamps on the files.  It has no way to determine if any intermediate file is actually valid or has been corrupted in some way -- as long as the intermediate file exists and is newer (more recently modified) than all of its dependencies, it will be used as is.
So what can happen (particularly when you are changing the Makefile itself) is that you can get a corrupt or incorrect intermediate file, which will result in a failure like the one you see even though the Makefile and all the source files are correct.
